# Responsive menu using only "nav" and "a" tags (no "ul")

Tags: css, html, tags

I was reading about semantics of HTML5 tags and I suddendly realized that the totality of CSS menus are done using unordered lists ( `ul` tag). Is there a particular reason behind that or is it possible to have a responsive menu using only the `nav` and `a` tags?

**State of the art:**

```
<nav class="nav_menu">
<ul>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"> Item 1 </a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"> Item 2 </a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"> Item 3 </a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.nav_menu {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
.nav-item {
  width:100%;
  float:none;
}
.nav-item a {
  display:block;
}
@media all and (min-width: 500px) {
  .nav-item {
    float:left;
    width:auto;
  }
  .nav-item a {
    padding:15px 20px;
  }
}
```

---

**What I want to achieve:**

```
<nav class="nav_menu">
    <a href="#"> Item 1 </a>
    <a href="#"> Item 2 </a>
    <a href="#"> Item 3 </a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.nav_menu{
    /*... blah*/
    @media all and (min-width : 500 px){
         /*... blah*/
    }
}
.nav_menu a{
    /*... blah*/
    @media all and (min-width : 500 px){
         /*... blah*/
    }
}
```

By responsive I mean a menu that stays horizontal when page is big enough otherwise it fallbacks to a vertical menu. I'm looking for a minimalistic solution without Javascript (if it is possible, otherwsie I'd like an explaination why it is not possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a minimalist solution you're wanting then CSS3's `Flexbox` would help you...

```css
.nav_menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.nav_menu a {
    padding: 1em 1.4em;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    .nav_menu {
      flex-direction: column; /* CHANGE THE FLOW OF THE ITEMS ON SMALL SCREENS */
    }
}

/* demo */
a{background: orange;}
a:nth-of-type(odd){background: yellow;}
```

```html
<nav class="nav_menu">
  <a href="#"> Item 1 </a>
  <a href="#"> Item 2 </a>
  <a href="#"> Item 3 </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Great that was a unexpected but wellcome answer :). It is even shorter than I thought

Comment: you're welcome @DarioOO. You can read more about `flexbox` here with some great examples. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: do you think reasonable just use flexbox hoping in it being widely adopted soon instead of "hacking" in order to support very old devices?

Comment: if you include something like modernizr to your site it will take care of that for you. https://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, there's no reason why you have to use an unordered list and list items. Semantically speaking, the anchors are a listing of anchors, so generally navigation menus are built out as such. But all the styles you put in place for the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements could just as easily be placed on the `<a>` themselves.

Comment: I tried and that do not work. I'm not a CSS advocate so I do not know the exact reason why that do not work